# WPF RichTextBox - Parent element from caret position

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Consider this document structure:

`<FlowDocument><Paragraph>loreM Ipsum</Paragraph></FlowDocument>`

And my caret position is between 'M' and 'I' in the RichTextBox. How can I get the parent element from caret position? *In this case the parent would be the Paragraph.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RichTextBox.CaretPosition.Parent
```

I think the parent element in that case will actually be a Run, and the parent of the Run will be the Paragraph.